# ASP.NET MenuItem that doesn't close when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

I am using an ASP.NET Menu Control in my website. If the user clicks on a menu item that has sub menus, I would want the menu to stay open and the page to do nothing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `DisappearAfter` property to -1 and it will wait for the user to click somewhere to close the menu.  See the Dynamic Appearance Timing section in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> The default value is 500 milliseconds. If the value of DisappearAfter
>   is set to 0, pausing outside of the Menu control causes it to
>   disappear immediately. Setting the value to -1 indicates that the
>   pause time should be infinite, and only by clicking outside of the
>   Menu control will the dynamic portion vanish.

Comment: thanks @Gromer. i tried it but it wasn't exactly what i was Looking for. the menu still closes.  My problem is I have a menu item that doesn't have a URL but has child nodes (submenus). if i click on this menu item, the menu closes, which i don't want to happen. What i want is when this menu item is clicked, the menu should stay open and don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the menu's RenderingMode property to List results to the desired behavior. However, this messes up the layout of the menu.